# Where should I ask my question about installing a program onto a tablet?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So I have a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1102918/install-a-program-on-a-tablet) about  installing a C# program that I have developed onto my Samsung tablet.

I have already asked it on SuperUser, as I thought since it was a compatibility issue, that would be the right place - the question addresses multiple formats, and SuperUser seemed to be the "middle ground". However it appears that is not the case.

So where should I ask this question?

---

**Disclaimer:** The question has already (technically) been answered in the comments, but I feel like this question is useful, so I want to ask it somewhere that it is on-topic.

Comment: FYI, [it's encouraged to answer your own questions.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Android SE might be suitable, but your question is deeply flawed, for the reasons I pointed out.  There are not that many people trying to run .NET applications on Android

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. My intention was to find out what the necessary approach to achieving this was, and step 1 is to not compile the program in .NET

Comment: Probably [android.se](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Are you compiling using xamarian?  It's really not clear at all what you're doing from your question.  For all we know, you've created a winforms app using .net 1.0 and you're trying to copy setup.exe to the tablet.  I'd say technical questions about deploying an .net app to an android tablet may be on topic for SO, but you DEFINITELY need to detail exactly what you're doing, how far you got, and what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to be about side-loading an app onto an Android tablet, [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) would seem to be the right spot.

Do be careful, however, as *development/programming* questions are *definitely* off-topic there.